# played video again automatically after finished

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am doing android application related Video Player.I played Video but I want to do When Video complete,it resumption with automatically in application how can I do? I am Using VideoView in my appliation.

```
    // Displays a video file.
    VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);

    String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.anket4dammy/"
            + R.raw.dunyagoz;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();

    mVideoView.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction();

    switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        // timer.cancel();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", false);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;


    }

    return true;
}


@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
    // video finish listener
    mVideoView
            .setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // not playVideo
                    // playVideo();

                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```